When connecting Android phone via USB it asks for access but Windows does not
Is there a way to avoid giving explicit permission to access files on the Android device when connecting to the Ubuntu machine with a USB cable?
I have two mobiles (Samsung, Note 8 and S23 Ultra), and every time I plug in a USB, it explicitly asks permission to let my Ubuntu notebook access files on the Android.
I understand that it is considerably reasonable privacy protection, but ... it does not happen on the same mobile and notebook booted with Windows 11 - it just connects. Files are instantly accessible in Windows Explorer without any need to click on the Android screen to give permissions.
How does this mechanism work in Windows? Or, to put it another way, is there any way to permanently grant access to the Ubuntu machine to avoid granting access to the files on the Android device every time?
--- Edit ---
I just found out that in the case of Windows, it is enough to unlock the Android phone and instant access to the files is given. Is there any Linux / Ubuntu setting that could cause similar behaviour instead of the need to click and allow access on the mobile?

As this is not a Windows support forum I suggest you ask the Windows questions in a Windows forum. Only Ubuntu support on this site.

"How does this mechanism work in the case of Windows?" I believe Windows doesn't have such protection in the first place, it just mounts the drive when plugged.

Thanks for the reply. I'm asking explicitly here because I'm Ubuntu, not a Windows user. I just realized such a mechanism exists in the case of Windows OS; thus, I wonder if there is any configuration setting in Ubuntu that would cause it to work similarly to the Windows mechanism I'm aware of.
